# How can I get the current URL or the URL clicked on and save it as a string in python?

Tags: python, string, url, wsgi, urllib

How can I get the current URL and save it as a string in python?

I have some code that uses encodedURL = urllib.quote_plus to change the URL in a for loop going through a list. I cannot save encodedURL as a new variable because it's in a for loop and will always return the last item in the list.

My end goal is that I want to get the URL of a hyperlink that the user clicks on, so I can display certain content on that specific URL.

Apologies if I have left out important information. There is too much code and too many modules to post it all here. If you need anything else please let me know.

EDIT: To add more description:

I have a page which has a list of user comments about a website. The website is hyperlinked to that actual website, and there is a "list all comments about this website" link. My goal is that when the user clicks on list all comments about this website, it will open another page showing every comment that is about that website. The problem is I cannot get the website they are referring to when clicking 'all comments about this website'

Don't know if it helps but this is what I am using:

```
z=[ ] 

for x in S:
    y = list(x) 
    z.append(y) 



for coms in z:
    url = urllib.quote_plus(coms[2])
    coms[2] = "'Commented on:' <a href='%s'> %s</a> (<a href = 'conversation?page=%s'> all </a>) " %  (coms[2],coms[2], url)
    coms[3] += "<br><br>"

deCodedURL = urllib.unquote_plus(url)
text2 = interface.list_comments_page(db, **THIS IS THE PROBLEM**)

   page_comments = {
           'comments_page':'<p>%s</p>' % text2,
           }


if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/conversation':
    headers = [('content-type' , 'text/html')]
    start_response("200 OK", headers)
    return templating.generate_page(page_comments)
```

Comment: How are they referring to the website in the actual page? Is it something like `<a href="all_comments.html">all comments about google.com</a>`?

Comment: We have a method to call the comments that will display all the comments about a URL <a href = 'conversation?page=%s'> all </a> should have the %s as the URL so then when you call interface.list_comments_page(db, url) would work

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is you need to parse the URL for the query string, and urllib has some helpers for that:

```
>>> i
'conversation?page=http://www.google.com/'
>>> urllib.splitvalue(urllib.splitquery(i)[1])
('page', 'http://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: link, page_url = urllib.splitvalue(urllib.splitquery(deCodedURL)[1])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1172, in splitvalue
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: This means your link didn't have a `?page=` part.

Comment: Just do a simple check: `parts = urllib.splitquery(deCodedURL); if parts[1]: # do the rest`